# Understand what a command does

Tags: att

I'm learning `x86` syntax.

I've stumbled across this command which I don't seem to be sure what it does:

```
cmpl $0x0,%cs:0x6574
```

I know `cmp` just compares the difference and sets the flags. And the `l` to indicate that unsigned values are being compared.

My question is:

What are we comparing ?

The value in `0x0` against what value `%cs:0x6574` ? 
cs register contains an address, should I add 0x6574 to it and extract the value ? something like:

```
mem[cs+0x6575]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is ATT syntax (not x86 syntax). By any chance is this OS development related? In particular are you looking at real mode JOS related code?

Comment: @MichaelPetch nice! yes. OSE, and I'm looking at JOS bootstrap code.

Comment: just before that CMPL instruction is used there is a `ljmp   $0xf000,$0xe05b` that will be done. That long jump has the effect of setting CS to $0xf000 and IP to $0xe05b. `%cs:0x6574` would be (0xf000) * 16 + 0x6574. That is physical address 0xf6574. I have not looked at that OSE/JOS code to know what is at that location but that compare is comparing the long word (4 byte value) at physical address 0xf6574 with the value 0.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank your sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is from real mode code it is default segment override. So instead of implicit DS use CS segment.
In real mode address calculation is a bit different. Value of segment is first multiplied by 16 and than offset is added.

So in your notation it will be

```
mem[16*cs+0x6575]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? are virtual addresses stored in the registers ? so hence you had to do a translate ? or does cs just point to the segment ?

Comment: What about `mov $0xf3c24,%edx` ? does it store the value in `0xf3c24` in edx ? or does it store the value in `16*0xf3c24+0` in edx ? I just ask so I can understand better :)

Comment: Translation always takes place in real mode. Real physical address is segment*16+offset - it is done inside CPU. If you use offset only what should matter for you is just offset. Of course there are additional addressing modes so you can use [base*scale+index+offset].